# show weekly days of month

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar

```
   public static void getWeeksOfMonth(int month, int year)
{
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd-MMM-yyyy");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

    int ndays = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    System.out.println(ndays+"<<<ff" );

    for (int i = 1; i <= ndays; i++)
    {
        String day = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
        System.out.println(day+"<<<" );
        Log.e("quest", day+"<<<");
        if(i % 7 == 0){
            Log.e("question", "=======week days===========");
        }
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

}
```

Output

Saturday 04-Nov-2017

Sunday 05-Nov-2017

Monday 06-Nov-2017

Tuesday 07-Nov-2017

=======week days===========

Wednesday 08-Nov-2017

Thursday 09-Nov-2017

Friday 10-Nov-2017

Saturday 11-Nov-2017

Sunday 12-Nov-2017

Monday 13-Nov-2017

Tuesday 14-Nov-2017

=======week days==========

Wednesday 15-Nov-2017

Thursday 16-Nov-2017

Friday 17-Nov-2017

Saturday 18-Nov-2017

Sunday 19-Nov-2017

Monday 20-Nov-2017

Tuesday 21-Nov-2017

=======week days===========

Wednesday 22-Nov-2017

Thursday 23-Nov-2017

Friday 24-Nov-2017

Saturday 25-Nov-2017

Sunday 26-Nov-2017

Monday 27-Nov-2017

Tuesday 28-Nov-2017

=======week days===========

Wednesday 29-Nov-2017

Thursday 30-Nov-2017

**1:-But i want complete last week Wed to Tuesday**

**2:-start weeks from Friday and end with Thursday**

Answer (score 1):

## Use *java.time*

You are using terrible old classes, now supplanted by *java.time* classes.

The [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class represents an entire month.

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY ) ;
```

Define your format for the output strings.

```
Locale locale = Locale.US ; 
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( 
    "EEEE dd-MMM-uuuu" ,
    locale 
) ;
```

I suggest instead letting *java.time* [automatically localize](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDate(java.time.format.FormatStyle)) for you rather than hard-code a format. To localize, specify:

- [`FormatStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.
- [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine:

  - The *human language* for translation of name of day, name of month, and such.
  - The *cultural norms* deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

Define formatter:

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( 
    FormatStyle.LONG , 
    Locale.CANADA_FRENCH 
) ;
```

Collect into a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) perhaps.

```
int initialCapacity = ym.lengthOfMonth() ;
List< String > outputs = new ArrayList<>( initialCapacity ) ;
```

Cycle through the days.

```
for( int i = 1 , i <= ym.lengthOfMonth() ; i ++ ) {
    LocalDate ld = ym.atDay( i ) ;
    String output = ld.format( f ) ;
    outputs.add( output ) ;
}
```

To group them by day-of-week, use the `DayOfWeek` enum.

```
DayOfWeek dow = ld.getDayOfWeek() ;
if ( dow.equals( DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY ) ) { … }
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).